# Behaviour of `*` and `_` immediately after `$ `

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Italics/emphasized text not working after a mathematical formula](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186/italics-emphasized-text-not-working-after-a-mathematical-formula)

I've noticed that sometimes if I try to emphasize text right after a mathematical formula, it will be parsed incorrectly. For example, compare the third paragraph in the two versions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/12267/revisions). In the first one, where I had written

> [...] remove *either* $(1,0)$ *or* $(0,1)$ [...]

which produced text in which the `*` were included and the `or` was not italicized. I edited and inserted a carriage-return just after `$(1,0)$` and just after `*or*`, and that resulted in an italicized `or`, fixing the problem. I've seen the same happen with bold text. I'm not sure why this happens. When I am previewing it seems to be okay, but not in the final product.

I'll try it here as well: this one has no carriage return, when we remove *either* $(1,0)$ *or* $(0,1)$.

Trying it again with a carriage return, we can remove *either* $(1,0)$
*or*
$(0,1)$.

Comment: Seen [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186) already?

Comment: @J.M.: No, I hadn't. I did a quick search but obviously did not hit on the right keywords, so I didn't notice it. The carriage return clearly works just like the "workaround" suggested.

Comment: I've gone ahead and edited the title of that question to include the keywords you might have searched for.